# Override void org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(Object input)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a class that extends org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog

I am using the org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer class like so..

```
private TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(newCntr, SWT.SINGLE|SWT.FULL_SELECTION|SWT.BORDER);

tableViewer.setInput(setOfObjects);
```

I will allow the user to do a delete from the UI. Instead of deleting from the set, I want to just mark that object with an attribute and not list it on the TableViewer. However, the TableViewer will list everything in the set. Should I go about overriding the method? I have provided it below... Thanks!

```
public final void setInput(Object input) {
    Control control = getControl();
    if (control == null || control.isDisposed()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Need an underlying widget to be able to set the input." + //$NON-NLS-1$
                        "(Has the widget been disposed?)"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    try {
        //      fInChange= true;

        unmapAllElements();

        super.setInput(input);

    } finally {
        //      fInChange= false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try to override `setInput`.

Instead use `TableViewer.addFilter` to add a filter to the table.

A filter is a class derived from `ViewerFilter`, it can select which elements of the table are displayed. This is an abstract class, you provide an implementation of:

```
public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element)
```

For a table `parentElement` is not used (filters can also be used with `TreeViewer`).

Use `TableViewer.refresh()` if the filter criteria change to get the table viewer to update.